# new badge, selected new goal, now previous new badge is shown in activity page

Tags: bug

I just earned a new badge on meta.stackoverflow. I am used to it taking a bit of time before a badge shows up on the badge overview in the activity page and/or in your recent achievements. That is no problem.

Going to the activity page on meta.stackoverflow, I was congratulated on my new badge and asked to select my next target. I accepted the proposed one. I am not sure if it happened immediately, but after a few minutes the new target "Next badge" is shown, combined with the **old** "Newest" badge (i.e. the now previously acquired one).

I remember which badge I just acquired. But this going back and forth in the same "BADGES" box on the activity page is a bit confusing. Either indicate that it is going to take time, or wait until all info is percolated through the databases before offering to choose the next badge.

---

After a chance to review my first suggested edit, the "Newest" badge is now "Custodian". The other badge did never show up in the BADGES box, nor is it visible in my Badges overview. The custodian is updated there, so there must be a different handling of different types of badges.

Comment: I posted a [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257856/186664) on [metase] about where to report this. I think this affects all sites with the new activity page, but I am not sure and not all sites have that new page (and the box in question) available. So it doesn't affect all sites (yet). That is why I posted the bug here and not on [metase]